# Web Audio: audio 2 sequential playbackRate values only applies first value

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a song that I'm playing with Web Audio and I schedule two playbackRate changes before I play the song. The first playbackRate change takes effect, but the second one never triggers. Is this expected behavior? Anything I'm missing to make this work?

Basic logic is:

```
sourceNode = _mySoureNodeGetterFn('blah.mp3');
sourceNode.start(0);
sourceNode.playbackRate.setValueAtTime(.8, 5);
sourceNode.playbackRate.setValueAtTime(1.2, 10);
audioContext.resume();
```

The second playbackRate value, `setValueAtTime(1.2, 10)`, scheduled for 10s into the song does not trigger. The first playbackRate triggers fine.

I'm using Chrome 56.0.2924.87 on a macbook.

Comment: This has already been reported https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=645776 (somehow) and is fixed in 58 canary. Also note that time param is relative to the audioContext's clock. There seems to be a new proposal to make it relative to currentTime if the value is already past, but currently no-one seems to have implemented it and you should call `setValueAtTime(val, audioCtx.currentTime + offset)`.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. Looks like this issue IS fixed in v58 canary. Though chromium bug seems to be a bit different from the one I'm seeing in that it occurs randomly / indeterminately where as my bug breaks every single freakin time. Solution is to wait for v58 then...

Comment: Yes, I think the core problem was the same, while the bug report is not exactly about the same issue. But it does work in 58 yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the loop - this is a bug with chrome v55. Fixed in v58 (dunno if fixed in any versions between the two).